# Possible to make the link autocompleter prioritize Tags before Posts?

Tags: block-editor

In the block editor's auto-completion dialog for linking, when I type something which matches both Posts and Tags, tag matches aren't show. It seems if the number of matches is too long, it's truncated; All I see are matching Post suggestions.

[image]

Is there a way to just change the priority? Show matching Tags first, then matching posts? Or a way to adjust how many matches are shown (so I can make it very large so the single tag that actually matches would at least appear waaay at the bottom)?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I figured it out. We need to:

- grab the editor settings
- wrap the fetch link suggestions function in our own function
- in this wrapper, we call the original, then do some sorting by `type`, in this case I changed it from ascending to descending so that `tags` comes before `post`
- update the editor settings with the replacement function

You still need to put this on the appropriate JS hook/promise so it runs once the block editor is loaded such as `wp.domReady(... )`, and enqueue it so it only runs on the post/page editor, but this is the code for the difficult part:

```js
window._wpLoadBlockEditor.then( () => {
    // grab the settings
    const oldSettings = window.wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getSettings();

    // create a replacement suggestion function
    const sortedSuggest = async (
        search,
        searchOptions = {}
    ) => {
        // grab the default suggestions:
        const promise = oldSettings.__experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions( search, searchOptions );

        // then when it finishes fetching them
        return promise.then( suggestions => {
            // sort the results, this is where you can re-order or change  the results, maybe add new ones, remove some, etc
            // Here we use a trick from stackoverflow to put the tags first:
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974069/sort-an-array-to-have-specific-items-first-in-the-array
            const sorted = suggestions.reduce( ( acc, element ) => {
                if ( element.type === 'post_tag' ) {
                    return [ element, ...acc ];
                }
                return [ ...acc, element ];
            }, [] );

            // return the new sorted results
            return sorted;
        } );
    };

    // Create a new settings object, and put our new suggestion function in it
    const newsettings = {
        ...oldSettings,
        __experimentalFetchLinkSuggestions: sortedSuggest
    }

    // update the editor with the new settings
    window.wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').updateSettings( newsettings );
} );
```

You can test this by copy pasting it into the browser dev console when the post editor is open, and searching.

[image]

Now that you have this, you should be able to modify the `sortedSuggest` function to change the sorting however you want, or even add/remove suggestions.

This is the structure it expects for each search result in the `results` array as defined by typescript:

```js
/**
 * @typedef WPLinkSearchResult
 *
 * @property {number} id     Post or term id.
 * @property {string} url    Link url.
 * @property {string} title  Title of the link.
 * @property {string} type   The taxonomy or post type slug or type URL.
 * @property {WPKind} [kind] Link kind of post-type or taxonomy
 */
```

e.g.

```json
[
    {
        "id": 298,
        "url": "https://frontenberg.tomjn.com/tag/welcome/",
        "title": "Welcome",
        "type": "post_tag",
        "kind": "taxonomy"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://frontenberg.tomjn.com/2017/11/04/hello-world/",
        "title": "Welcome to the Block Editor",
        "type": "post",
        "kind": "post-type"
    }
]
```

Comment: D8 …thank you! I'll try dropping it into my site-function plugin's functions file and report back :)

Comment: note that all of this is javascript, you'll need to put it in a JS file, and enqueue it so it loads only when the block editor loads, and probably wrap it in a JS hook so it runs at the right time. This is only copy paste in the sense that you can copy it into the browser dev console, it's not a finished plug and play product

Comment: ¡ thanks for the clarification. I have some admin-only css that loads so I _think_ I can get that working ;)

Comment: I've [a screenshot of a j/s error](https://constantine.name/20221102-screenshot.png)… I wrapped it in a wp.domReady(function () {…}), enqueued, step debugging and after stepping, "sortedSuggest: function()" shows it's arguments:" as "TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context."

Comment: …maybe that's not a problem. It seems to step debug fine, and the link auto-completion still works, but the results aren't reordered with the tag at the top.

Comment: I have no idea what that error means, I'm not familiar with Safaris browser dev tools. Perhaps safari doesn't support the `{ ....variable }` syntax? Eitherway this problem is not a WP problem but a generic javascript problem

Comment: I fired up Safari and copy pasted my code into the console and the error did not happen. Note that I don't know the exact error, I don't know how you enqueued it, etc, and I do not know if `wp.domReady` is the correct method, it was more a direction I was pointing in for further research. Keep in mind this is not a full copy paste solution to drop into a project

Comment: also googling suggests that this specific error is usually coupled with mentions of javascript strict mode, but I do not see how that relates to what I shared. Again it works fine for me in both Chrome and Safari on WP 6.0/6.1, perhaps it's the sorting arrow function and replacing it with a named function `function thing() {}` style function would solve that. Eitherway I think it's moving beyond the scope of the question and answer

Comment: 1) upon further poking— I think that error is just when I open the properties of the object in the inspector.  2) and I hadn't done this originally, but when I paste your js into my Safari console (after verifying I don't have my version of it also enqueued) it doesn't alter the behavior of my link suggestions  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  I was hoping this would be easier, but I'm clearly too far out of my depth. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: note that it sorts by the kind/type, so if there are no tag suggestions or there's a post that appears higher in the alphabet, e.g. a custom post type that starts with Q or higher, then this won't put tags at the top. Tags have a type of `post_tag`. The point is that it puts the sorting in a function you can mess with using generic JS

Comment: @CraigConstantine I updated the code, but keep in mind that the root problem you're having is a basic "How do I sort an array of objects in javascript" problem. I've tried to make it specifically and explicitly sort tags to the top, specifically post tags. This is about as close as you will ever get to a copy pasta solution. Put it in a file and enqueue it in the block editor, note it uses modern JS features such as async/await, promises, and object destructuring, so you will want a babel/webpack build setup for optimal usage

Comment: Thanks for your continued tinkering on this. I've given up on trying to make it do what I want—it's all too complicated for my skills :)